# Does the template function generate new child scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to replace the `ng-repeat` directive with a custom one written by me. Here is the definition object link function:

```
    //directive definition object...
    //...
    ///link: function (scope.......)
        function buildList(entries){  
            var i, 
                timeline = [],
                tplCopy,
                tplFunct;

            for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                tplFunct = $compile(entries[i]);
                timeline.push(tplFunct(scope.$new()));
            }
            DOMelement.append(timeline);
        }
```

where `scope` is the one in which my directive works and `entries` is a list of NodeElement.

This works just fine except for one thing: the scope binded to the single entries through `tplFunct` is a child of the new one that I specifically created.

So my question is: does `tplFunct (scope.$new())` bind a child of the given scope intead of the scope itself?

edit. 
Is possble that the new scopes are generated by an `ng-controller="foo"` directive inside the `entries`? Even if the binded controller doesn't have a `$scope` service inside of it?

[ngcontroller docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

> Two different declaration styles are included below:
>
> one binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using this: 
>      ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings"
>
> one injects $scope into the controller: ng-controller="SettingsController2"

Comment: As you're explicitly calling `scope.$new()`, a new child scope will be created and your `tplFunct` will be bound to that scope. If you want your template function bound to the scope itself, then you should do `tplFunct(scope)`. This will result in all elements bound to single scope object. Is that what you intend to accomplish ?

Comment: @Arkantos what I'm saying is that A CHILD of the "scope.$new()" scope is binded, this is the problem. so we have parent scope -> sons scopes -> grandsons scopes